# Printing elements in a string list by index C++

Tags: c++

Hi here is what I have so far. The operation printList(strList,indexList) will print the elements in strList that are in positions specified by indexList but im having trouble doing so. I'm trying to use the public STL container operations but having trouble. Any help would be great! Thank you!

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<list>
using namespace std;

//  PURPOSE:  To have the user enter strings into list 'strList'.  No return value.
void enterStringList(list<string>&strList){
while (true){
    string  entry;
    cout << "Please enter a string or just press 'enter' to quit: ";
    getline(cin, entry);

    if (entry.empty())
        break;

    strList.push_back(entry);
}
}

void enterIntegerList(list<int>& intList, int limit) {
    bool shouldContinue = true;

while (shouldContinue)
{
    int     number;

    do
    {
        string  entry;

        cout << "Please enter an integer [0-"
            << limit
            << "], or just press 'enter' to quit: ";
        getline(cin, entry);

        if (entry.empty())
        {
            shouldContinue = false;
            break;
        }

        number = atoi(entry.c_str());
    } while ((number < 0) || (number > limit));

    if (shouldContinue)
        intList.push_back(number);
}
}


//  PURPOSE:  To print the elements in L that are in positions specified by P.
//  No return value.
void printList(list<string>& strList, list<int>& indexList){
//  HERE }

int     main() {
list<string>    strList;
list<int>   indexList;

enterStringList(strList);

if (!strList.empty())
{
    enterIntegerList(indexList, strList.size() - 1);
    indexList.sort();
    printList(strList, indexList);
}
return(EXIT_SUCCESS);}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your problem seems to be that you don't know how to write the `printList` function; the code you have written is irrelevant to the question. This is a help forum, not a free code-writing service. I advise you to try writing a function that prints *one* element of a list, and build up from there.

Comment: Try the following approach: put your rubber duck -- see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging for more information -- next to your keyboard, then explain to your rubber duck, in plain English, your proposed algorithm for implementing your function. Phrase your explanation as a logical, step by step process, in your own words. When you finally convince your rubber duck that your algorithm will work, and your rubber duck agrees, then just take your verbose explanation, and translate it into code. Easy.